# Is $AM = AM[2]$?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, game-theory

Any $k$ round AM can be reduced just two rounds whereby Arthus just does the $k$ coin tosses and passes on the information to Merlin. Merlin sees all the coin toss results and computes everything necessary since he knows Arthur's function as well.

So for any $k$, $AM[k] = AM[2]$
And one anyway has, $AM[k] \subseteq AM[k+1]$

So doesn't it follow that $AM = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} AM[k] = AM[2]$?

Comment: Yes, see [AM at Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#am).

Comment: Yes, but note $k$ has to be constant (independent of $n$), if $k$ can be any polynomial of $n$ the class becomes PSPACE.

Comment: What do you mean that "$k$ has to be a constant"? $k$ is going over all the positive integers and it has nothing to do with any other parameter here.

Comment: @user6818: It's possible to define $AM[k(n)]$, where $k$ depends on $n$; in this case the number of rounds can depend on the input size, and the class becomes larger (it's the IP=PSPACE result); for any positive integer $k$, $AM[k]=AM$, and likewise $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} AM[k]=AM$, but this result no longer holds for classes such as $AM[n]$.